# iOS: How to add an image on top of all rows in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have to add one background rectangle image on top of all rows in `UITableView`.

For example, please check the below reference image where a red arrow indicates this image.
This image is appended in tableview itself, because if I scroll the `tableView`, this image moves alongwith it.

[image: an image on top of all the rows in tableview]

I'd like to know how to insert such an image on top of all rows in `UITableView`.

I added UITableView in XIB and displaying contents handled in coding.
Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UITableView` has `tableHeaderView` property

Example:

```
UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 130.0f)];

UIImageView *thumbnail = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 130.0f)];
[thumbnail setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[initDictionary objectForKey:@"cover_image"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
thumbnail.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
thumbnail.clipsToBounds = YES;
[header addSubview:thumbnail];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
```

Ref: [`UITableView` Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView)

Comment: In viewWillAppear, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view and set is as a `tableHeaderView` property of your `UITableView`.

Example:

```
// Create a view.
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 
                                                              0.0f, 
                                                              320.0f, 
                                                              70.0f)];
// Customize your view.
// ...

// Set the view as a table view header.
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

You can place this code for example in `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller. Here is what documentation says about it:

> **tableHeaderView**
>
> An accessory view that is displayed above the table.

Based on [UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView)

Answer (score -1):

You have to mix dynamic with static cells, only the first cell will be static in this case, with the code something like:

```
    #pragma Mark TableView DataSource Methods
    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

        return 2;
}

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   if(section == 0){
            return 1;
        }else{

        return 10;
    }

    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.section == 0 ){
       //Static cell 
        static NSString *idCell = @"cell";

        UITableViewCell * cell  = (UITableViewCell * )[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

       return cell;
        }

    //Then you code your dynamic cells...



    }
```

Hope it helps!